# Dependency not accept

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have this problem : My dependency org.apache.poi can not accept in pom.xml
this dependency lighting red. But i add in project module jars:

poi-5.2.2
poi-ooxml-5.2.2
commons-collections 4-4.3
commons-compress-1.18
xmlbeans-3.1.0
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9
dom4j-1.6.1

all jars i am add but dependency not accepted and continue lighting red: my code

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you using Intellij? If so are you right clicking on the pom and reloading it to pick these up? If that's not it, what's in your Maven settings.xml?

Comment: The `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9` does not fit to `poi-ooxml-5.2.2`. It would must be `poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.2`. Also `xmlbeans-3.1.0` does not fit. It would must be `xmlbeans-5.0.3`. Also... see: https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Maven coordinates are correct.

Here is an example POM based on the artifact [`maven-archetype-quickstart`](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/), with updated versions on all items, and with your your two dependencies pasted as-is. And I updated the `import` statements in the `AppTest.java` file to use JUnit Jupiter. So we have fully-working, up-to-date, practical example app.

Your dependencies are processed correctly by Maven. This app compiles and runs. I did this in IntelliJ 2022.1.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TryDep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>TryDep</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

As a sanity check, I suggest you create and run a new project using that POM posted above.

In your own problematic project, I suggest you make sure Maven processed your POM. In IntelliJ, either:

- Click the little floating [windoid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/windoid) with a Maven logo: *M*.
- Click the two arrows in a circle icon in the *Maven* panel, a button whose tooltip says *Reload All Maven Projects*.

[image: screenshot of two buttons to reprocess Maven POM]

Then execute a Maven *clean* and *install*. (You can see the *clean* item in screenshot above.)

Your [local Maven cache](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) in a `.m2` folder may need to download the dependencies. This downloading may take several minutes depending on the speed of your Internet access.

On occasion, the Maven local cache goes wonky. If all else fails, [clear the cache](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-clear-cache) by deleting the entire `.m2` folder. Then do another *clean* and *install* which in turn should trigger creation and population of a fresh `.m2` folder.

Comment: "little floating windoid" omg lol hilarious but _so frustrating_ that intellij makes this windoid so obscure. Been searching for an hour how to refresh dependencies after changing the pom.xml

Comment: @ryvantage Yes it is a f frustrating situation. Your Comment prompted me to add a screenshot for clarity. Thank you.